# Jordan normal form

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, jordan-normal-form, functional-calculus

Let $H$ a Hilbert space and let $T\in B(H)$ a bounded operator on H, my question is if it exist a theorem about some "decomposition" of type Jordan canonical form in a general Hilbert space, and how we can do it.

Comment: You should look into [holomorphic functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus) for a suitable generalization. The generalization for compact operators is particularly nice.

Comment: I know it exist something like that in the case of compact operator, but how ?

Comment: As far as I know it is still an [open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_subspace_problem) if any bounded operator on a Hilbert space has a non-trivial closed invariant subspace.

Comment: Yeah that true , but what we can say about normal operators or subnormal operators because they have a invariant subspace .@A.G.

Comment: See [the Jordan normal form for compact operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Compact_operators) and [the spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Compact_self-adjoint_operators)